# Short preview of emails in Outlook shows the image src and not the alt text

Tags: email, outlook, html-email, mjml

I have a problem when I genereate email via MJML. The email looks great, but there is a problem in Outlook where it shows the source url of the first image in the mail instead of texts or the alt-text  in the short description of the email. I'm expecting it might have something to do with that we use CDN to hosts our images, but I have no clue. See the image below:

[image]

Does anyone know what I can do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why its not showing your alt text, it should work that way, in any case you can always add your preview text to the html directly after the body tag and hide it with css like this:

```
<body>
    <div style="display:none;font-size:1px;color:#ffffff;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;margin-right:100%;">
        Your Preview Text Here 
   </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Definately worth a try! I'll let you know after I've tested how it went :)

Comment: Different mail providers generate the preview text in varying ways. Outlook has decided to include URLs for whatever reason, so this is the answer.

Comment: This solution works. I just included the first few lines twice, once in the hidden div at the beginning and then as normal afterwards. Hacky, but works.